# I can't get results with .contains Swift5

Tags: swift, contains, resultset, swift5

```
func gettinSongName(){

    let folderUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.resourcePath!)

    do {
        let songPath = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: folderUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
        for song in songPath{
            let mySong = song.absoluteString
            if mySong.contains("mp3") {
                print(mySong)
            }
        }
    } catch  {

    }
}
```

I get no results when I write this code

but I get results when I type `.contains("a")`

```
 func gettinSongName(){

    let folderUrl = URL(fileURLWithPath: Bundle.main.resourcePath!)

    do {
        let songPath = try FileManager.default.contentsOfDirectory(at: folderUrl, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: .skipsHiddenFiles)
        for song in songPath{
            let mySong = song.absoluteString
            if mySong.contains("a") {
                print(mySong)
            }
        }
    } catch  {

    }
}
```

result:

> file:///Users/xzips/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/637C5530-3899-4D61-8AFB-8B0EC6A52D09/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/5EFA5FA9-2928-409E-B80C-A0A7F0A8E423/Bebek%20Ninnileri.app/_CodeSignature/
>   file:///Users/xzips/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/637C5530-3899-4D61-8AFB-8B0EC6A52D09/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/5EFA5FA9-2928-409E-B80C-A0A7F0A8E423/Bebek%20Ninnileri.app/songs/
>   file:///Users/xzips/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/637C5530-3899-4D61-8AFB-8B0EC6A52D09/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/5EFA5FA9-2928-409E-B80C-A0A7F0A8E423/Bebek%20Ninnileri.app/Base.lproj/
>   file:///Users/xzips/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/637C5530-3899-4D61-8AFB-8B0EC6A52D09/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/5EFA5FA9-2928-409E-B80C-A0A7F0A8E423/Bebek%20Ninnileri.app/Assets.car
>   file:///Users/xzips/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/637C5530-3899-4D61-8AFB-8B0EC6A52D09/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/5EFA5FA9-2928-409E-B80C-A0A7F0A8E423/Bebek%20Ninnileri.app/Info.plist
>   file:///Users/xzips/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/637C5530-3899-4D61-8AFB-8B0EC6A52D09/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/5EFA5FA9-2928-409E-B80C-A0A7F0A8E423/Bebek%20Ninnileri.app/Bebek%20Ninnileri
>   file:///Users/xzips/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/637C5530-3899-4D61-8AFB-8B0EC6A52D09/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/5EFA5FA9-2928-409E-B80C-A0A7F0A8E423/Bebek%20Ninnileri.app/PkgInfo

Comment: There are no `mp3` in the result. try printing out all files and look if there is `mp3` at all.

Comment: Double check if `folderUrl` is valid and if `songPath` has any contents.

Comment: type contains('"m") and you will see if you get something but no mp3 inside

Answer (score 1):

The dedicated API in `Bundle` to get all resources of a specific extension is

```
func gettinSongName() { 
    if let mp3Urls = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension "mp3", subdirectory: nil) {
        for song in mp3Urls {
            print(song)
        }
    }
}
```